# Mail content shows as html code in Joomla 3

Tags: php, email, joomla, joomla3.2

I have written a script for sending a mail, it gets delivered to the correct email address but in them form of HTML code, I don't know why it's not working as same code is working fine in Joomla 2.5.

Here's my code:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$subject = 'Account Created';
$from   = $config->get('mailfrom');
$fromname = $config->get( 'fromname' ); 

$body = "<p>Hello Test F,</p><br/><p>Thank you for registering at Deals&offers. Your account is created and activated.</p><br/>You may login to ".JURI::root().'index.php'." using the following username and password:</br><p>Username: ".$fname."</p><p>Password: ".$pwd."/p><br/><p><b>Note:</b> It is recomended to change your password after first login.</p>";

$sender = array( 
    $from,
    $fromname
);

$mailer->setSender($sender); 

$mailer->addRecipient($buyerEmail);

$mailer->setSubject($subject);

$mailer->setBody($body);

$send = $mailer->Send();

if ( $send !== true ) {
    echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->message;
} else {
    echo 'Mail sent';
}
```

I have also tried like below, but got same result.

```
JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($from,$fromname,$buyerEmail, $subject, $body);
```

the output I got in the mail is:

```
<p>Hello Test F,</p><br/><p>Thank you for registering at Deals&offers. Your account is created and activated.</p><br/>You may login to http://server.ashoresystems.com/~dealsand/index.php using the following username and password:</br><p>Username: rowdy</p><p>Password: lX1XZghF/p><br/><p><b>Note:</b> It is recomended to change your password after first login.</p>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anyone has any solution please help.

Comment: I am not familiar with any joomla version, but i think you must specify body type manually. may be older version detect it manually, but in new version are not. Try `$mailer->isHTML(true)` ([here example](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

For your first method...You have to set

```
$mailer->isHTML(true);
```

Reference : http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

For your second method...

Sendmail function :

```
sendMail($from, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $body, $htmlmode=0, $cc=null, $bcc=null, $attachment=null, $replyto=null, $replytoname=null )
```

so your code should be

```
JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($from,$fromname,$buyerEmail, $subject, $body,true);
```

Comment: Yap, both of given method working for me thanks for the help.